# One KafkaConsumer listening to multiple partitions VS multiple KafkaConsumers listening to multiple partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have ten Kafka Producers each one writing to different partition of a topic.

I cannot tell which is more effective.

Having one consumer listening to the ten partitions or having ten consumers listening to different partition?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between these two ways. But remember when you have ten consumers there is overhead for connecting each consumer to Kafka.

If there is a capability in consuming different partitions by one consumer so probably it is enough performant.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if you have multiple consumers, you'll be able to get more throughput, since you'll have multiple threads/applications pulling data from the kafka cluster, which means you'll be able to parallelize across multiple cores, and maybe multiple servers.

However, you also need to take into account what you're trying to accomplish.  Does one process/application need to look at all the data?  Are the messages independent of each other?  All of this will inform how your application should be designed.

In a default configuration, all of the available partitions for a topic will be distributed evently across all consumers with the same group id.  So, you could have one consumer, and it will automatically grab all partitions for that topic.  Or you could instantiate ten consumers, and each consumer will get exactly one partition in this case.

Comment: I have taken under consideration before asking my question that consumer is not thread safe. Does that mean that 10 consumers run on a single thread? Or not?

Comment: You're correct, the `KafkaConsumer` is not thread-safe.  However, that only means that you shouldn't share the consumer instance between threads.  You can safely run a _different_ consumer across 10 different threads.

Comment: If the messages are not independent of each other what is the best practice?

Comment: There's multiple things you can do like: Assign a key to a message when producing them (say, a user_id for all messages related to that user), ensuring that the same consumer will get all the related messages.  You can also simply consume and immediately put the message in an internal queue, where some other thread will handle them separately, without having to know which partition/consumer they came from.